# Linq sql exception: "Row not found or changed error"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have simple program that insert object to the DB of sql server. It worked well for hours and suddenly I got the Exception

> "ChangeConflictException: Row not found or changed error"

and then it didn't stop (i.e. threw the exception over and over again for every insert)

The code for the insert is:

```
    lock (DBManager.DB_LOCK)
    {
        DBManager.Instance.ExecutionDB.MarketStrikesDatas.InsertOnSubmit(baseRecord);
        DBManager.Instance.ExecutionDB.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

and the exception is:

> System.Data.Linq.ChangeConflictException: Row not found or changed.
>          at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
>          at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)

The object is very simple and contains several double fields and DateTime fields. All are `NOT NULL` both in DB and in the dbml.

The system is multithreaded and I have two tables.

Comment: Check primary key definitions. This error may occur when you already have record with same key in db.

Comment: @Krzysztof i checked the primary key and didn't find problems there. Also as i wrote once it happened it didn't stop happening so it was not a broken record case.

Comment: I'm not sure why your error occurred originally, but I would suspect you are not creating a new DataContext for each insert, so once you get an error like this, the next call to SubmitChanges will attempt to post the first record as well as the second.